# Issue faced while migrating from PyQt4 to PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, migration, pyqt4, python-2to3

I have an GUI application, which is quite big.I have it in Python 2.7. Since Python 2 is no longer being updated, I converted my application to Python 3.8 using 2to3 module. I am facing this problem and have no idea how to solve it. I referred some of the similar problems but did not get anywhere. I have the following error:

> QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)
> TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, bytes, bytes, bytes): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'

What should I do to get pass this issue?

Comment: Have you generated the resource files again?

Comment: Sorry. I did not. I am quite new to this. How do I do it?

Comment: The same way you created it. You probably used `pyrcc resource.qrc -o resource.py`. If you have both PyQt4 and PyQt5 it should be `pyrcc5` (or `pyrcc5.exe`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource files on PyQt are actually python scripts with base64 encoded data.

When porting to newer systems (both python 3 and Qt5) requires proper updating of those files.

Generally, it can be done by calling again the `pyrcc` command (`pyrcc5` or `pyrcc5.exe` if both Qt versions are installed), but they *can* be manually ported, considering the following aspects:

- the import statement has obviously be modified to `PyQt5`;
- all variables (`qt_resource_data` and `qt_resource_name`) are [*bytes literals*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) and require the `b'...'` prefix;

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore

qt_resource_data = b"\
    -- raw data --
"

qt_resource_name = b"\
    -- raw data --
"
```

Comment: I would have upvoted your answer, but could not because of my reputation points. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sash7 don't worry, the important thing is that it's marked as accepted. Keep following and interacting on SO and you'll easily get [more reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).